# Question about the usual top on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

This question arose from @MISC {
TITLE = {Understanding the proof interval is connected subspace of $\Bbb{R}$},
URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4856769}
}

Suppose $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ with subset topology, $U$ is an open subset of $A$, do we still have $\forall x \in U$, there exists $\epsilon$, such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset U$, I think we only have some $\epsilon$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \cap A \subset U$. However, if $A$ is an interval, it seems to work. However, I do not have a good way to prove it without tedious discussions of the various types of intervals.

Comment: This works if and only if $U$ is contained in the interior of $A$ (interior relative to $\mathbb{R}$). In particular when $A$ itself is open.

Comment: The version with "$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \cap A \subset U$" is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subspace $A=[0,1]$ , clearly $U=[0,\frac{1}{5})$ is open in $A$ and $0 \in A$ but there is no $ \varepsilon >0$ such that $(0-\varepsilon,0+\varepsilon)\subset U$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second remark is correct. It is $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap A\subseteq U$ that we have. Once you restrict to the subspace $A$, it is as if the points of $\Bbb R\setminus A$ do not exist. The open ball of radius $1$ about $0$ within the subspace $[0,2]$ is just $[0,1)$; this is exactly $(-1,1)\cap[0,2]$, and the "other points" $(-1,0)$ do not exist in this subpace $[0,2]$. More formally, the subspace topology is literally defined in this way; if $X$ is a space and $Y$ a subspace then $W\subseteq Y$ is open in $Y$ iff. $\exists U\subseteq X$ an open of $U$ such that $W=U\cap Y$.