# Understanding the proof interval is connected subspace of $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

This proof is from Bradley's 'Topology A Categorical Approach'. I have some questions about the details. I remarked parts that confused me.

Suppose $I$ is an interval with $I=U \cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are nonempty, open and disjoint. **(I believe here $U$ and $V$ are open in subset topology)** Then there exist $x \in U$ and $y \in V$, and we may assume $x<y$. Since the set $U^{\prime}=[x, y) \cap U$ is nonempty and bounded above, $s:=\sup U^{\prime}$ exists by the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, since $x<s \leq y$ **(Why $s>x$, can it equal to $x$?)** and $I$ is an interval, either $s \in U$ or $s \in V$ and so $(s-\delta, s+\delta) \subseteq U$ or $(s-\delta, s+\delta) \subseteq V$ for some $\delta>0$. **(Why? My last question shows it may not be true @MISC {
TITLE = {Question about the usual top on $\Bbb{R}$},
URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4856736}
})** If the former holds, then $s$ fails to be an upper bound on $U^{\prime}$. **(Why?)** If the latter, then $s-\delta$ is an upper bound for $U^{\prime}$ which is smaller than $s$. **(I partly understand since $(s-\delta, s+\delta) \not\subset U$)** Both lead to a contradiction.

Comment: For your first question: Why do you believe so? The definition of connected usually requires open sets in the topology your looking at, not the subset topology

Comment: Second question: We assume X<y (why can we do so?) What would U' look like if s=x?

Comment: Third question: that's simply by definition of U, V being open in the natural topology and s being in one of those sets by assumption of I=$V\cup U$

Comment: Fourth question: consider $s+\frac{\delta}{2}$

Comment: Regarding your last question: that's the reason, which part do you think you don't understand?

Comment: For the first comment, A subset is connected iff it is connected in subspace topology, so here $U$ and $V$ are open sets in subspace topology. For the second comment, we have $U'=\{x\}$, any contradictions here? For the third comment, here $U$ may not be open in the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh yes I remembered the definition wrong. 2. How do you want to get U'={x}? Not that U is open (in the subset topology) and $x\in U$

Answer (score 1):

Your first comment is completly right (as you mentioned).
Regarding your second question:
Assume $x=s$, which would imply $U'={x}=[x,y)\cap U$. This means $x$ is an upper bound of U.
Now we know $U=I\cap T$ for some open $T$ and that $I$ contains some bigger number than $x$, (we assume $y>x, y\in I$).
There exists some $\delta>0$ with $[x,x+\delta)\subseteq I$, but as $T$ is open, x is an inner point of $T$ and there exists some other $\delta'>0$ with $(x-\delta',x+\delta')\subseteq T$, so with $\epsilon = \min\{\delta',\delta\}$ we have $[x,x+\epsilon)\subseteq U$. (basically T can't have a maximum value it takes, I doesn't have x as it's maximum value).
Now regarding your third question:
I agree that the proof explains poorly, why the statement is true. There is essentially only one case to worry about. If $s$ is in the interior of $I$, the statement is clear (as $U=T\cap I$ and both of those then include a neighborhood of s).
So the only case to worry about, is if $I$ is of the form $[t,s]$ or $(t,s]$. ($s\in\partial I$). (As $x<s$ it can't be a lower bound of $I$). Now in that case, $s=y$ has to be true, ($s\leq y$, $y\leq s$ both hold). But that would be a contradiction to the case $s\in U$ we are looking at! So $s$ has to be in the interior of $I$. In the second case I'm honestly not sure if $[s,s+\delta)\subseteq V$, but we only need $(s-\delta,s]\subseteq V$ anyway.
I hope everything here is clear, feel free to ask any questions